# Problems with the graphical representation of the decision tree algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm doing some work using Decision Trees on Python, using scikit learn. The classifier itself works absolutely fine, however when I create a graphical representation of this, I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-101-98cefceb177f> in <module>
      4                filled=True, rounded=True,
      5                special_characters=True,feature_names = ["Campo di applicazione", "Scala temporale", "Scala spaziale", "Semplicità", "Economicità", "VET"],
----> 6                class_names=["Sì", "No"])
      7 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
      8 graph.write_png("cds.png")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py in export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file, max_depth, feature_names, class_names, label, filled, leaves_parallel, impurity, node_ids, proportion, rotate, rounded, special_characters, precision)
    762             rounded=rounded, special_characters=special_characters,
    763             precision=precision)
--> 764         exporter.export(decision_tree)
    765 
    766         if return_string:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_export.py in export(self, decision_tree)
    397                                  "does not match number of features, %d"
    398                                  % (len(self.feature_names),
--> 399                                     decision_tree.n_features_))
    400         # each part writes to out_file
    401         self.head()

ValueError: Length of feature_names, 6 does not match number of features, 5.
```

I'm trying different ways, but it keeps giving me the same problem, how can I solve it? Thank you so much in advance for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Length of feature names doesn't match with number of features' error while plotting decision tree using Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826905/length-of-feature-names-doesnt-match-with-number-of-features-error-while-plot)

Comment: No, unfortunately! I tried, but it keeps giving me mistakes.